# Can I tag all AWS resources for which I am charged?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

There are some services in AWS which are free and there are some services/resources in AWS for which AWS charges. Such as for AWS Cloudformation, IAM, Consolidated billing services are free of cost where as for S3, EC2 it charges.

Can anyone specify me clearly for which AWS services I am charged and for which services I am not charged?

```
Also, I have enabled the cost allocation report for my account. Can I tag all the
resources for which I am charged so that I can get full clarity of the resources 
which are been used and for which I am been charged, in my cost allocation 
report?
```

Answer (score 1):

You can tag only the resources which are mentioned in below link:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_Tags.html#tag-restrictions

Comment: Out of these resources for which resources I am charged in AWS?

Comment: This will take a bit of reading. you need to glance through the AWS documentation of various services. I could not find a single page where it is clearly differentiated between chargeable and free services. e.g. VPC is a free but the NAT instance inside it is not...

Comment: It will take a lot of time to go through each and every service. Any other idea?